# Create and load data (objects)

Tags: c#, .net

I have a fairly expensive calculation (30 minutes each).  Actually 169 of the same.  I want to just run them once and load them.

```
private List<Hands> Hands = new List<Hand>() {new Hand(...), new Hand(...)};
```

My plan is to just run the program and have it print out all the new Hand(...) and then I will copy paste it into the program.

Is there a better way to go about this?

I would rather not use a database or external XML.

```
 Debug.WriteLine("HoleCards holeCards = new HoleCards(new Card({0}), new Card({1}), {2}, {3}, {4}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}, {12}, {13}, {14}, {15}, {16}, {17}, {18}, {19}, {20});",
                            holecards.Card1.CardInt, holecards.Card2.CardInt, holecards.Wins, holecards.Loses, holecards.Ties
                          , holecards.StrFlush, holecards.Quads, holecards.Boat, holecards.Flush, holecards.Straight, holecards.Trips, holecards.TwoPair, holecards.OnePair, holecards.High
                          , holecards.StrFlushLose, holecards.QuadsLose, holecards.BoatLose, holecards.FlushLose, holecards.StraightLose, holecards.TripsLose, holecards.TwoPairLose, holecards.OnePairLose, holecards.HighLose);
```

Comment: Why not just serialize them (not necessary to xml, to some binary format)?

Comment: @Evk That is not a bad idea.   I will look into it.

Comment: One good option for this is protobuf (https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net). Quite fast, binary, small footprint (if your class contains two int properties - basically in serialized form it will be just those two ints).

Comment: By the way, since that is related to evaluating poker hands, you might want to look to different existing evaluation algorithms (for example here: http://www.poker-ai.org/archive/www.pokerai.org/pf3/viewtopic4bef.html?f=3&t=16). Best of them use huge lookup table stored on disk (like you want to do) with clever algorithms to evaluate hand in just 5-7 array lookups, which allows them to perform more than 100 million evaluations per second on average machine.

Comment: @Evk That is what I would like to figure out.  Do you know any fast lookup evaluators in C#.

Answer (score 2):

This does not answer question, but in comments OP asked for fast lookup evaluator in C#. You can use so called "two plus two evaluator". It's a big precomputed lookup table which you can use to lookup strength value of a given hand.

Here is some code in C#.

```
public static class Card {
    private static readonly Dictionary<char, int> _suites = new Dictionary<char, int> {
        {'c', 0}, {'d', 1}, {'h', 2}, {'s', 3}
    };

    private static readonly Dictionary<char, int> _ranks = new Dictionary<char, int> {
        {'2', 1}, {'3', 2}, {'4', 3}, {'5', 4}, {'6', 5}, {'7', 6}, {'8', 7}, {'9', 8}, {'T', 9}, {'J', 10}, {'Q', 11}, {'K', 12}, {'A', 13}
    };

    public static Dictionary<char, int> Ranks => _ranks;

    public static int FromString(string c) {
        if (c.Length != 2) throw new ArgumentException("c");
        char rank = Char.ToUpperInvariant(c[0]);
        char suit = Char.ToLowerInvariant(c[1]);
        return (_ranks[rank] - 1)*4 + _suites[suit] + 1;
    }
}
```

Card just converts a card from string representation ("As" for A spades and so on) to int representation expected by evaluator we use.

```
public class RankEvaluator
{
    readonly string[] _handTypes = new[] {
        "invalid hand",
        "high card",
        "one pair",
        "two pairs",
        "three of a kind",
        "straight",
        "flush",
        "full house",
        "four of a kind",
        "straight flush"
    };
    private RankEvaluator()
    {

    }
    private int[] _lut;
    private void Init()
    {
        _lut = InitIntl();
    }

    private static readonly Lazy<RankEvaluator> _instance = new Lazy<RankEvaluator>(() => {
        var r = new RankEvaluator();
        r.Init();
        return r;
    }, true);

    public static RankEvaluator Instance => _instance.Value;

    private int[] InitIntl()
    {
        var lut = new int[32487834];
        if (!File.Exists("HandRanks.dat")) throw new InvalidOperationException("HandRanks.dat not found");
        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open("HandRanks.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)))
        {
            var tempBuffer = reader.ReadBytes(32487834 * 4);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(tempBuffer, 0, lut, 0, 32487834 * 4);
        }
        return lut;
    }

    public int LookupHand(params int[] cards)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int p = _lut[53 + cards[0]];
            p = _lut[p + cards[1]];
            p = _lut[p + cards[2]];
            p = _lut[p + cards[3]];
            p = _lut[p + cards[4]];
            p = _lut[p + cards[5]];
            return _lut[p + cards[6]];
        }
    }

    public string GetType(int value) {
        return _handTypes[value >> 12];
    }

    public int GetRank(int value) {
        return value & 0x00000fff;
    }
}
```

This class loads HandRanks.dat file with huge lookup table into memory and implements simple algorithm necessary to lookup hand strength. You can get dat file [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am0hxlnsevPPmAI-nY5O3uG_VWiu).

Use like this:

```
var hand1 = "As Ah";
var hand2 = "2s 2c";
var board = "5s 2d 8h 8s Ks";
var fullHand1 = (hand1 + " " + board).Split(' ').Select(Card.FromString).ToArray();
var fullHand2 = (hand2 + " " + board).Split(' ').Select(Card.FromString).ToArray();
var r1 = RankEvaluator.Instance.LookupHand(fullHand1);
var r2 = RankEvaluator.Instance.LookupHand(fullHand2);
var type1 = RankEvaluator.Instance.GetType(r1); // two pairs
var rank1 = RankEvaluator.Instance.GetRank(r1);
var type2 = RankEvaluator.Instance.GetType(r2); // full house
var rank2 = RankEvaluator.Instance.GetRank(r2);
Debug.Assert(r2 > r1); // full house wins
```

That's just basic implementation but starting from this you can do many things (evaluate change of winning of one hand vs another on preflop, flop, turn, compare hand vs range of other hands and so on).

Comment: I figured out an evaluator that runs in under a second and does not use a table or database.

Comment: @Paparazzi great, but "under a second" seems not too fast, because this one can perform millions evaluations per second :)

Comment: I may need to come back to this.  Mine will evaluate the 2.6 million starting hands in 1 second.   But I am going to come to give this one another look.

Comment: Sure, it is just hard to beat 7 array lookups in terms of perfomance. Feel free to ask of something is not working -  I had it working fine before.

Comment: Could you tell my how the 7 array lookup works?  I mean like under that covers?

Comment: Algorithm to build lookup table is quite complicated (and I don't remember details as of now) and all sources (like twoplustwo forum or codingthewheel site) are archived or not available now, so I'm not sure how to get the actual description. Evaluator's name is "RayW hand evaluator" and all I could find is this github project: https://github.com/WhatMatters/ray_eval. There you can at least find the algorithm to generate lookup table (in C++), though without much comments.

Comment: If you have some doubts if lookup table is correct - you can compare result of evaluations with any other evaluator, for all possible hands. You can also build your own lookup table with the C++ code provided in previous comment. If you just want to know how algorithm works - it seems as of now you have to just look at source code to generate it (except you will be more lucky than I am and will be able to actually find description anywhere).

Comment: Thanks but I don't know C++.   I am more of a mathematician.   I am not doubt the table is correct.  I just wanted to know how they work.

Comment: I understand, but as I said unfortunately I cannot find a human description of that algorithm any more (all sites it was on are either archived or unavailable now). However, it's not required to really _know_ C++ to read source code to generate that table. Here is the file: https://github.com/WhatMatters/ray_eval/blob/master/src/raygen7.cpp. As you see, there are not much C++ specific things there. If you know what is pointer and how bitwise operations work - you might be able to understand the algorithm.

Comment: Here is one link with description of _another_ algorithm: http://suffe.cool/poker/evaluator.html. But, this algorithm is used (I think), at least partially, to build lookup table. Note also the link at the very bottom of linked article.