# Poker hand representation and evaluation

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

A poker deck is 52 card
13 rank and 4 suit

Working on efficient hand representation and evaluation

```
A    K    Q    J    T    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2
scdh scdh scdh scdh scdh scdh scdh scdh scdh scdh scdh scdh scdh
```

52 bits

As, Ac, Qs Qh, 8s, 7s 6s

```
A    K    Q    J    T    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2
scdh scdh scdh scdh scdh scdh scdh scdh scdh scdh scdh scdh scdh 
1  1      1  1                1    1    1
```

It is breaking at 9 cards 36 bits
It is fine up to the last set

```
byte s = 1;

UInt16 spades4 = (UInt16)((s << 12) + (s << 8) + (s << 4) + (s & 0xff));
Debug.WriteLine("Hexadecimal value of {0} is {1} {2}", spades4, String.Format("{0:X}", spades4), Convert.ToString(spades4, 2).PadLeft(16, '0'));
Debug.WriteLine("");

UInt32 spades8 = (UInt32)((s << 28) + (s << 24) + (s << 20) + (s << 16) + (s << 12) + (s << 8) + (s << 4) + (s & 0xff));
Debug.WriteLine("Hexadecimal value of {0} is {1} {2}", spades8, String.Format("{0:X}", spades8), Convert.ToString(spades8, 2).PadLeft(32, '0'));
Debug.WriteLine("");

Int64 spades9 = (Int64)( (s << 30) + (s << 28) + (s << 24) + (s << 20) + (s << 16) + (s << 12) + (s << 8) + (s << 4) + (s & 0xff));
Debug.WriteLine("Hexadecimal value of {0} is {1} {2}", spades9, String.Format("{0:X}", spades9), Convert.ToString(spades9, 2).PadLeft(36, '0'));
Debug.WriteLine("");

// once the shift is up to 31 it breaks - it goes negative
Int64 spades9b = (Int64)((Int64)(s << 31) + (Int64)(s << 28) + (Int64)(s << 24) + (Int64)(s << 20) + (Int64)(s << 16) + (Int64)(s << 12) + (Int64)(s << 8) + (Int64)(s << 4) + (Int64)(s & 0xff));
Debug.WriteLine("Hexadecimal value of {0} is {1} {2}", spades9b, String.Format("{0:X}", spades9b), Convert.ToString(spades9b, 2).PadLeft(36, '0'));
Debug.WriteLine("");
```

I have tried UInt64 and same problems

I think this is the fix
Don't know I should delete of leave this up

```
Int64 spades9b = (Int64)(((Int64)s << 44) | ((Int64)s << 40) | ((Int64)s << 36) | ((Int64)s << 32) | (Int64)(s << 28) | (Int64)(s << 24) | (Int64)(s << 20) | (Int64)(s << 16) | (Int64)(s << 12) | (Int64)(s << 8) | (Int64)(s << 4) | (Int64)(s & 0xff));
Debug.WriteLine("Hexadecimal value of {0} is {1} {2}", spades9b, String.Format("{0:X}", spades9b), Convert.ToString(spades9b, 2).PadLeft(48, '0'));
```

Comment: I think this is the fix ((Int64)s << 32)

Comment: Hopefully you are doing it just for fun, because there already exist VERY efficient algorithms of poker hand  evaluation.

Comment: @Evk Could you point me to one in C#?

Comment: I answered one such question, herei it is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40852652/5311735. Algorithm itself is very simple (7 array lookups), all idea is in lookup table. If you would want to know how that lookup table is built - google "two plus two evaluator". PS: that was your question :) Didn't work as expected?

Comment: @Evk I could not make the lookup evaluator work in C#.

Comment: That's strange, given that it just makes array lookups. Anyhow if you would like to discuss what went wrong - you can comment on that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Definitely use UInt64 (for everything, including `s`, which you didn't show) and also ...
2. Use `|` instead of `+` because it's more idiomatic for bitwise operations. For the signed Int64, the + is probably causing you some issues because the largest positive number is half the range.

Once you do both, if it still has issues, post your new code and what the output is.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to these kind of problems is:

- Make one Enumeration of values.
- Make one Enumeration of colors/symbols/whatever we are calling it today.
- Make a struct, class or tupel that takes one of each value.
- The Deck and each players hand is a List of that struct, class or tupel. I use list because it is easier to "remove" elements from those.

Encoding it into one Integer is possible. But I would not advise it. Of course your question might *actually* be about the specific implementation of the value types in memory and not about poker hands, so I might be totally off.

Comment: I am trying to make a faster elevator using bit masking and some other tricks I found in a java library.  The easy to use is not fast enough for millions of hands.